# Understanding the '&' operator

Tags: c++, c

As of what I know about '&' operator, it returns the base address of the operand in memory.

Let us imagine the following scenario (as on my machine):

- sizeof(int) = 4 bytes
- sizeof(float) = 4 bytes
- sizeof(char) = 1 byte

Now, if I write something like this:

```
void main() {
 int i = 5411;
 int *ip = &i;
 char *c = &i;

 printf("%d",*ip);
 printf("%c",*c);
}
```

The first printf() should give me 5411. Talking about the second printf(), the base address of i contains 10101001 (higher order 8 bits = 1 byte for char type pointer).
Hence *c should give me 169, which when converted to %c is an invalid character.

But the compiler is giving me '#' or some other valid output. Why is it so ? Any inputs ?

**EDIT** (taken from the author's comment on one of the answers):

> That was just a dummy case, since I was away from the actual machine.
>   
> The actual case is i = 5411

Comment: In any case, if you try to "print" a "char" it will be displayed as a char, not as the corresponding integer code.

Comment: probably something to do with char encoding being used, I would guess.

Comment: Yeah I too agree with that. But there must be a reason for getting '#' value from the last printf(). It's not a garbage value.

Comment: Your shell may be replacing "invalid" characters with `#`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 130 instead of 144?

Comment: @Gaurav Kalra: actually, there is no guarantee you will get 114 as a result. You are counting on endienness (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) to get 144, but not all systems are little endian.

Comment: This question parses strangely.  Glancing at the title, then the accepted answer I assumed it was about the binary '&' operator.  Then it turned out to be about the unary & operator.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You seems to have trouble understanding how integers are stored in memory. Take 5411 as example.

```
5411 = 1010100100011
```

this number 13 binary digits has however, since an `int` is 32-bit, it must be pad to 32 digits

```
5411 = 00000000 00000000 00010101 00100011
```

On a little endian machine (x86, ARM by default), the least significant bytes are stored in the front, so in the memory:

```
00100011   00010101    00000000    00000000
^
c          c + 1       c + 2       c + 3
ip
```

Therefore, `*c` should return 00100011 i.e. 35 (`'#'`).

Comment: Where did `5411` come from? The OP's code clearly initializes `i` with `1154`.

Comment: @AndreyT: See OP's comments on other answers.

Comment: Someone with question editing privileges should edit the question.

Comment: @PigBen: Okay, I did that. Sorry for creating little confusion

Answer (score 5):

ASCII only defines characters up to 127. Besides that, what you really want to do is print the numeric corresponding to the value in `*c`, this is also done using `%d`...

```
 printf("%d",*c);
```

...should display the number as you expect.

Comment: That was just a dummy case, since I was away from the actual machine. The actual case is i = 5411. %c gives '#' and %d gives 35 (instead of 169)

Comment: @Guarav: ASCII still only defines characters up to 127, and what you really seem to want is to print numbers, so print numbers, not characters.

Comment: @Gaurav -- Why are you expecting 169?  On a little endian machine, it should be 35.  On a big endian machine, it should be 0.

Comment: -1 for "extended ASCII" instead of specifying a character encoding. There is no such thing as "extended ASCII".

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, your program is ill-formed. Neither C nor C++ allows initializing an `char *` pointer with an `int *` value. You need an explicit cast in your initialization of `c` pointer.

Secondly, which byte of the original integer `i` - higher order or lower order - resides at its "base address" is implementation-defined. There are little-endian architectures, where the lower-order but will be seen through `*c` (which is has value `130` on a 8-bit `char` machine, not `114`). And there are big-endian architectures, where the higher-order but will be seen through `*c` (which is `0` on a 8-bit `char` machine). So you should expect either character with code `130` or character with code `0` to be printed with `%c` format specifier.

Thirdly, in a typical implementation there's normally no such thing as "invalid character code". For any code something will usually be printed in one way or the other. I don't see though how you managed to obtain `#` as the output from your code. Is this the real code you were running?

Comment: Hi Andrey. 1-> The code is compiling. Should I care for explicit casting then? ... 2-> Yeah, I was not aware of this, which KennyTM answered ... 3-> I mentioned, it's a dummy code

Comment: @Gaurav Kalra: Compiling as what? You tagged you question [C] and [C++]. This code will not compile as C++ by any self-respecting C++ compiler. C compilers with overly relaxed error checking might allow that (with a warning), but the code is still illegal even as C, so if you care about writing valid C code the cast is required.

Answer (score 1):

The Address of *c is that of i, because you have assigned c to &i. It will then take the highest or lowest (depends on the endian) and print that character.

Comment: The case of i = 5411 is printing '#' as the character. An ASCII of 35 (10101001), which is neither the upper 8 nor lower 8 bits.

Comment: @Gaurav -- 35 in binary is 00100011

Comment: Agreed. There won't be a truncation with the *c because the character pointer is large enough to hold the entire value of the memory location.

Comment: @Gaurav Kalra: Why are you saying it was `1154` in your original post, and the saying it was `5411` in the comments? `1154` and `5411` are two different numbers, if you noticed.

Comment: Am sorry for that: That was just a dummy case, since I was away from the actual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Just to learn something about the encoding of your integers you should experiment a bit and do

```
printf("0x%X, %X|%X|%X|%X\n", 
  i, 
  i & 0xFF,
  (i >> 8) & 0xFF
  (i >> 16) & 0xFF
  (i >> 24) & 0xFF
  );
```

An then do the same with `c[0]`, `c[1]` etc and other format strings as `%c`.